# Adding metadata to a HTML5 audio stream

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Is there any way to add metadata to a live radio audio stream played through a HTML5 audio element? Currently the stream has no metadata and the radio streaming software we use to generate the stream file cannot add metadata to it. Is there a way to add appropriate metadata in (such as setting the artist to the radio station name) through JS so that the audio appears correct on mobile (for instance: the iOS notification area)

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the software you're using for generate the stream file? - had you checked the documentation of the software.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Myriad + AudioTX WebStream but we can't licence Myriad OCP to send metadata between the two.